# how to make highchart x axis meet y axis at min value of yAxis

Tags: highcharts, axis, min

i have a highstock chart and i set min value in yAxis, what i need is that xAxis line cross yAxis on specified min value of y axis, but there is a gap between them?

```
yAxis: {
  opposite: true,
  crosshair: false,
  min:10000,
},
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6t70fhs/)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the yAxis option [startOnTick](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.startOnTick) to false, that to force a start from the first tick that is your minimum.

```
   yAxis: {
     startOnTick: false,
     max: 80000,
     min: 10000,
   },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wjgqd1yn/